# How can i know when "Share Link" Button is clicked?

Tags: ajax, facebook, share

I am using old Facebook sharer with a button that is a link to facebook.com/sharer.php?u=LINK on my home page, because there is a lot of content that need to have some share button, but like buttons make it very slow.

So, now i made my own design of fb sharer, so when I click on share button, ajax loads a box with iframe to fb sharer.

Now I am interested if I can now when a "Share Link" button is clicked, or "Cancel" button, so that I can automatically close my box (like the original popup window is closed when those buttons are clicked)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it states in the [documentation of the Share](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/):

> The Share button has been deprecated in favor of the Like button, and
>   will no longer be supported. Please use the Like button whenever
>   possible to drive maximum traffic to your apps.

Since it's no longer supported, there are drawbacks of using it.
With the [Like button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) you can simply subscribe to the like event:

```
FB.Event.subscribe("edge.create",
    function(response) {
        alert("You liked the URL: " + response);
    }
);
```

I don't think that there's a way to know that with the old share.

Comment: does something else need to be included with this? I am using the default code provided by facebook and i get an error that FB is undefined

Comment: just follow the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.3, when `window.fbAsyncInit` is called then it's safe to use the FB namespace

Comment: Does this mean I will have to write new code for the like/share button? I have it working with the code from Facebook but the Facebook buttons are slow to load so I want to keep this efficient

Comment: You probably won't be able to write your own like/share button, you don't have much choice but to use whatever facebook offers.